# Can you get $g_{\mu\nu}$ from $R^\lambda_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

From the Christoffel symbols it is easy (although cumbersome) to get the Riemann tensor $R^\lambda_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ from the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. But is it possible to reverse the procedure? Is there a way to express the metric tensor in terms of the Riemann tensor?

Comment: not really, because it'd be in terms of integrals, not simple algebraic expressions

Comment: I can think of a simple analogy. Let's say we start with function $f(x)$ and define $g(x)=f''(x)$. Can we reconstruct $f(x)$ from $g(x)$? The answer is that this is not really possible, because there are two constants left undetermined since the derivative kills constants. Likewise if I give you $f(x,y)$  and define $g(x,y)=\partial_{x}^2f(x,y)$ and we try to find $f(x,y)$ from $g(x,y)$ the situation is even worse because now the two constants are two functions of $y$.

Comment: Your question is a much more complicated version of this. Given the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ we construct $R^\mu_{\phantom\mu\alpha\beta\gamma}$ by taking several first and second order derivatives of $g_{\mu\nu}$ with respect to various of the coordinates. Inverting this relation would certainly involve a number of undetermined functions. In other words, the relation between the Riemman tensor and the metric tensor is not one-to-one and therefore you can't really invert it and uniquely specify the metric in terms of the Riemann tensor.

Comment: @Gold, I would say that your comments are so great that you should have posted them as answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you can definitely express the Riemann tensor in first and second derivatives of the metric tensor, the metric tensor is not uniquely determined by it. The Riemann tensor is given by the Connection coefficients and their first derivatives. Using the comma "$,$" to indicate differentiation it can be written as:

$$ R^{\rho}_{\sigma\mu\nu} = \Gamma_{\nu\sigma,\mu}^{\rho} - \Gamma_{\mu\sigma,\nu}^{\rho} + \Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^{\rho}\Gamma_{\nu\sigma}^{\lambda} - \Gamma_{\nu\lambda}^{\rho}\Gamma_{\mu\sigma}^{\lambda}\tag{1}$$

And the Connection coefficients, assuming we are using the LC connection, are given by:

$$ \Gamma_{\nu\sigma}^{\rho} = \frac{1}{2}\left(g^{\rho\alpha}(g_{\alpha\nu,\sigma}+g_{\alpha\sigma,\nu}-g_{\nu\sigma,\alpha})\right)  \tag{2}$$

Plugging $(2)$ into $(1)$ we obtain:

$$ R^{\rho}_{\sigma\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(g^{\rho\alpha}\left(g_{\alpha\nu,\sigma}+g_{\alpha\sigma,\nu}-g_{\nu\sigma,\alpha}\right)\right)_{,\mu}-\left(g^{\rho\alpha}\left(g_{\alpha\mu,\sigma}+g_{\alpha\sigma,\mu}-g_{\mu\sigma,\alpha}\right)\right)_{,\nu}   \right] +
\frac{1}{4}g^{\rho\alpha}g^{\lambda\beta}\left[\left(g_{\alpha\mu,\lambda}+g_{\alpha\lambda,\mu}-g_{\mu\lambda,\alpha}\right)\left(g_{\beta\nu,\sigma}+g_{\beta\sigma,\nu}-g_{\nu\sigma,\beta}\right)-\left(g_{\alpha\nu,\lambda}+g_{\alpha\lambda,\nu}-g_{\nu\lambda,\alpha}\right)\left(g_{\beta\mu,\sigma}+g_{\beta\sigma,\mu}-g_{\mu\sigma,\beta}\right)\right] $$

This can be made to look slightly simpler, but that is beside the point. To solve the above system of PDE means (in $4$ dimensions) recovering the $10$ independent components of the metric tensor via this PDE system that has a total of $20$ equations, one for each independent component of the Riemann tensor. Despite having "only" $10$ functions to recover via $20$ equations, a large number of degrees of freedoms in fact exist in the form of the first and second order partial derivatives of the metric tensor, although obviously those are not all completely independent functions. As @Gold mentioned with a nice example in a comment, even with a very small number of derivative functions such a problem yields a non unique solution. I refer you to this [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438173/does-every-curvature-tensor-induce-a-metric) for more mathematically related comments about this problem.

Another interesting fact I stumbled upon which pertains to this: apparently in Riemann normal coordinates, one can express the metric as a function of the Riemann tensor in a neighborhood, [more details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates#Explicit_formulae). Again, this doesn't yield a unique & global solution.

It would be interesting, and more physics related (as opposed to purely mathematical) to also note that it does make some intuitive sense: the metric tensor fully encodes the spacetime geometry, and I don't find it very surprising that many different geometries can yield the same spacetime curvature. Hence, also from the equations we see that it's quite straightforward to uniquely determine the curvature from the geometry, but not the other way around.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page you link, there appears a vector $x^\mu$ and an error of order $O(|x|^3)$. Do you know the meaning of $|x|^3$? I don't get if it is the magnitude of $x^\mu$ because of notation (the standard is $||x||$) or what other thing would it be.

Comment: @Antoniou It means third order corrections and higher in the coordinates. I've found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712092.pdf) that derives a fuller expansion and you can see it there (it was linked from a comment in this [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631639/metric-in-terms-of-the-connection))

Comment: Thank a million!

Comment: The system of equations being overdetermined would suggest the opposite to what you conclude here.

Comment: Note that the quoted equation is derived in Riemann normal coordinates, and is valid only at a single point. It cannot be interpreted as a PDE. As an algebraic equation at a point all the (100) second order derivatives of the metric count as independent degrees of freedom. The equation is under determined (as is consistent with the rest of the answer).

Comment: @TimRias Thanks! That's indeed a blunder on my part, I've quoted the wrong equation. The [next answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3752017/707918) in the same thread however shows that you can express the Riemann tensor in terms of the metric tensor's first *and* second derivatives, so it still looks like finding a solution over a domain is overdetermined... I understand your remark about being underdetermined if considering the equation I quoted that's indeed relevant at a point, but I actually did want to point out the over determinacy when looking for a solution over a domain.

Comment: "... meaning, although you can definitely express the Riemann tensor in first and second derivatives of the metric tensor, the metric tensor is not uniquely determined by it." This is still not what overdetermined means. (See also your own edit.)

Comment: @TimRias It seems to me there is some lack of wide agreement on what overdeterminacy means in the context of a system of PDE... if you would please look [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system) you would find it agrees with the terminology I am using... It's clear however that in fact it's the degrees of freedom in the $100$ second order partial derivatives of metric that make up the parametric freedom which makes the metric non-unique.... I would say this is just a case of confusing terminology

Comment: I none of the uses does it imply that the solution of an over-determined system is non-unique as the first sentence of this answer still claims!

Comment: @TimRias Thank you for your comments, I've entirely avoided the mention of the terms over or under determinacy in the latest edit.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. Finding the metric tensor requires finding a solution to the EFEs.

It's important to understand that the Riemann tensor tells us how the metric tensor varies across some interval, while the metric tensor describes the overall structure of spacetime.

Essentially, you can think of it as the Riemann tensor containing less information than the metric tensor does, so you can't derive the metric tensor from it.

Answer (score 2):

Although, the question posed by OP is an overdetermined problem, it is interesting to note that the number of independent components of *Weyl Curvature* (only the trace free part of $R_{abcd}$) in $d$ dimensional space-time is $\frac{1}{12}d(d+1)(d+2)(d-3)$, which turns out to be 10 when $d=4$. Thus, there are as many unknown metric functions as (known) Weyl components. So we can ask if it is possible to  reconstruct vacuum metric components from Weyl curvature.

A review on estimating perturbed metric components in terms of [Weyl scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_scalar) on background Kerr spacetime has been discussed in [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/22/15/003). As of now, the construction involves gauge issues, odd behaviors of perturbation near it's source, inability to capture the perturbed mass and angular momentum of the system.

A different perspective can be obtained from the [non-linear graviton construction](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00762011) in *Twistor theory*, which provides a recipe to construct self-dual/anti-self dual Weyl curvature and metric satisfying vacuum Einstein's equations from a specified twistor function $f\in H^1(\mathbb{PT}^+;\mathcal{O}(2))$. This function generates a spin 2 zero rest mass field ($\varphi_{ABCD}$) in $\mathbb{CM}^+$ using *Penrose transform*. The vague idea is that if we write our line element as
$$ ds^2=(\eta_{ab}+2\lambda \Sigma_{ab})dx^adx^b$$
then the unknown components $\Sigma_{ab}$ can be computed from taking derivatives of the twistor function $f$ (see $\S$9.2 from [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/twistor-geometry-and-field-theory/B1E6211CC3D935029ABD1D30B68B9360)). Once we know the metric, we can evaluate the Weyl curvature spinor $\Psi_{ABCD}$ and when restricted till order of $\lambda$, it is proportional to $\lambda\varphi_{ABCD}$. Conversely, if we are provided with *linearized Weyl curvature* $\varphi_{ABCD}$, we can do *Inverse Penrose transform* to obtain the twistor function $f$ and evaluate $\Sigma_{ab}$

Comment: "As of now, the construction involves gauge issues, odd behaviors of perturbation near it's source, inability to capture the perturbed mass and angular momentum of the system." As of now? Most of these issues have been addressed since that review was published.

Comment: @TimRias Ohh..I wasn't aware of the recent work. In that case the answer should be updated. Can you provide the reference/ current work on this problem?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1513, https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01227, https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00969, https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.09095, https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.04273, https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2276

Comment: Thank you for the references! Actually I just rechecked the article I mentioned in my answer, and noticed it was published in 2005. Yeah, so its old

Answer (score 1):

A very simple counterexample: let $g_{\mu\nu}$ be a flat metric (i.e. $R\equiv 0$). Then for $\alpha\in\mathbb R_{>0}$, if $\alpha\ne1$, $\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$ is a different metric, but still flat.

Comment: $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$, are related by a coordinate transformation, and therefore still describe the same Riemanian manifold.

Comment: @TimRias This transformation is not an isometry though, I just mean that for the same coordinates you scale the tensor. In other words, if the distance between two points was $d$ in the first metric, it will be $\alpha d$ in the other. If you do this on a sphere, you actually change the curvature.